# Python updates through Eclipse

Tags: python, html, eclipse, eclipse-kepler

How do I get Python updates through Eclipse Kepler Version?

I previously used to download it from the Google Apps Engine website, but since January 2014 Google recommended using Eclipse to get automatic updates for Python. However, when I downloaded Eclipse Kepler it did not contain Python. It only contains Java.

Comment: Eclipse is written in java. There is no python source for eclipse.

Comment: You should at least mention in your question what operating system you're using, and if your looking for some a python 2 or python 3 runtime.

Comment: Where does Google say that?

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse has several plugins that support developing software with Python (PyDev, for example). None of those include a Python runtime and they never did. So you probably misunderstood something.

My guess is that when you say "Python", you actually mean "the app engine framework for the Python language".

As far as I can tell, you still get that from Google: https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_Python

Now there is also a plugin for Eclipse which adds extended support for developing App Engine applications. You get that from Google as well: https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/getting_started